# Running jQuery.each() on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code;

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    $("input:text").each(function (index, value) {
        var el = $(this);
        if (el.val().length == 0) { el.css('border', '1px solid red') }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here, all the input text elements are dynamically created hence I can never validate whether they are empty or not..

How do I go and use `.on()` with `.each()` ? I googled with no luck.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: That code should work as long as the elements are created before the button is clicked. `.on()` is used for attaching events.

Comment: This looks like it will work fine, what problem are you having?

Comment: Why do you return false every time each calls your function?

Comment: Thank you for your help.. btnSave was an asp.net button which was causing postback. When I turned it into a standard button, it somehow worked.. I don't know why but I'll check...

Answer (score 4):

Your code is pretty much fine, but get rid of the `return false;`. It stops the `.each()` loop after the first input is hit.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ujTFG/)**

Answer (score 2):

It should not be a problem until and unless the elements are not on the page when you click on the page..
Also because you are returning return false ; when the field is empty only the first textbox will be given the border.. Others will be left out even when empty..

Try this

```
​$(function() {
    $('#btn1').on('click' , function() {
        var inp = '';
        for(var i=1;i< 6;i++){
           inp += '<input type="text" id="txt' + i + '"/>'
        }   
        $('.textboxes').append(inp);

       var isError = false;
       $("input:text").each(function (index, value) {
            var el = $(this);
            if (el.val() == '') { 
               el.addClass('error');
               isError = true;
            }
        });

            if(isError){return false;}    
    });    

});​
```

Also check this working example...  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/PP99g/)